# How do I allow only internal network to access a particular UDP Port using iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I want to allow Asterisk access (UDP Port 5060) to internal network only (192.168.3.0/24 and 192.168.4.0/24) and not allow external access.

Relevant part of my iptables was:

```
 iptables -F
 iptables -t nat -F
 iptables -A INPUT -p udp -j ACCEPT
 iptables -P INPUT DROP


 iptables -I INPUT -p udp ! -s 192.168.3.0/24 --dport 5060 -j REJECT
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp ! -s 192.168.4.0/24 --dport 5060 -j REJECT
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp  -s 192.168.3.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp  -s 192.168.4.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
```

This does not work.

I use NAT for a different purpose.

Comment: The INPUT chain is for packets coming in to the box you are running them on. It seems like you need to substitute the INPUT rules for FORWARD rules.

Comment: Also, a more effective rule might be to block forwarding to or from port 5060 on the WAN interface.

Comment: @davidgo  I am running Asterisk on this very server so I thought the INPUT chain is the one to be controlled?

Comment: You might want to describe your setup in more detail then. Using the INPUT table is appropriate.  Your rules above seem to be rube-goldberg complex - acting multiple ways on the same traffic for different ranges and being order specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing a sequence of inserts into `iptables`:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp ! -s 192.168.3.0/24 --dport 5060 -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp ! -s 192.168.4.0/24 --dport 5060 -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp  -s 192.168.5.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp  -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
```

As these are each inserted as the first rule, the order is effectively reversed:

```
-A INPUT -p udp  -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp  -s 192.168.5.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp ! -s 192.168.4.0/24 --dport 5060 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -p udp ! -s 192.168.3.0/24 --dport 5060 -j REJECT
```

This means traffic from `192.168.3.0` will be rejected by the third rule and not reach the fourth rule.

Your question says internal networks are `192.168.3.0/24` and `192.168.4.0/24` so it is not clear why you are accepting `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.5.0/24`.  Nonetheless, you should write the rule to accept the local subnets and reject everything else, e.g.

```
-A INPUT -p udp -s 192.168.3.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -s 192.168.4.0/24 --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 5060 -j DROP
```

Comment: The identification of local networks was a typo. I have corrected it. You pointed me in the right direction.